# creating custom checkbox in NUXT js that can accept and set unique values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a custom checkbox component that can accept and set values like [this vue component](https://jsfiddle.net/opeodedeyi/u520krjv/1/), but I have no success in doing this

below is what I have tried:

below is the parent component,
in the data.idealfor array I would like the value passed their checkbox to me automatically ticked, just like the js fiddle link posted above

```
<template>
    <div>
        <checkinput name="dinner" val="dinner" v-model="form.idealfor">Dinner</checkinput>
        <checkinput name="wedding" val="wedding" v-model="form.idealfor">Wedding</checkinput>
        <checkinput name="party" val="party" v-model="form.idealfor">Party</checkinput>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: {
        checkinput
    },
    data() {
        return {
            idealfor: ["wedding"]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

below is the child component

```
<template>
    <div v-if="controlType === 'checkbox'" class="checkbox bounce">
        <input type="checkbox" :name="name" v-model="checked" :value="val" @change="onChange">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 21 21">
            <polyline points="5 10.75 8.5 14.25 16 6"></polyline>
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        controlType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: 'checkbox'
        },
        val: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data () {
        return {
            checkedProxy: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        checked: {
            get () {
                return this.value
            },
            set (val) {
                this.checkedProxy = val
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your parent component like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <checkinput name="dinner" val="dinner" v-model="idealfor">Dinner</checkinput>
        <checkinput name="wedding" val="wedding" v-model="idealfor">Wedding</checkinput>
        <checkinput name="party" val="party" v-model="idealfor">Party</checkinput>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default 
{
    components: 
    {
        checkinput
    },
    data() 
    {
        return 
        {
            idealfor: ["wedding"]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and then your child component like this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="checkbox bounce">
        <input type="checkbox" :name="name" v-model="checked">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 21 21">
            <polyline points="5 10.75 8.5 14.25 16 6"></polyline>
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default 
{
    props: 
    {
        name: 
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        val: 
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value:
        {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
        }
    },
    computed: 
    {
        checked: 
        {
            get () 
            {
                return this.value.includes(this.val)
            },
            set (newVal) 
            {
                const current = this.val
                this.$emit('input', newVal ? this.value.concat([current]) : this.value.filter(item => item !== current))
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```